# Redo Git Merge in a Pull Request

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have branch X which I would like to merge into master on GitHub. After resolving a merge conflict and merging master to X, I merged the pull request to master. I then realized that I have resolved the initial merge conflict incorrectly, resulting in a broken master. I used the "revert pull request" button on GitHub to bring master to a working state. How do I bring X back to the state right before merging master to X so that I can redo the merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not committed any changes both for branch `X` and `master`, then you can redo the merge with below commands:

```
# In local git repo
git checkout X
git pull
git reset --hard HEAD~
git checkout master
git pull
git reset --hard HEAD~
git push -f --all
```

Now both the branches are go back to the versions before you merged `master` into `X` branch.

And now, you can merge `master` branch into `X` branch by resolving the conflict as you want, and then create a PR to re-merge branch `X` into `master`.

Answer (score 0):

Find the hash of the commit right before you performed the merge and run `git reset --hard <commit hash>`

You may want to checkout a new branch just in case something goes wrong with the reset.